# How to acces specific object value in array?

Tags: php, dropbox

I'm working on dropbox API so I can build image gallery from path, but I'm kinda stuck in this array. I want to access image's path value from this array. Also show it to as dropbox image gallary. Please help me. I'm kinda stuck! Thank you.

```
Array
(
    [code] => 200
    [body] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [rev] => 246830441
            [thumb_exists] => 1
            [photo_info] => stdClass Object
            (
                [lat_long] => 
                [time_taken] => 
                [image_dimensions] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 1128
                        [1] => 2407
                    )

            )
            [path] => /DSC_0528.JPG
            [is_dir] => 
            [client_mtime] => Tue, 29 Mar 2016 17:39:12 +0000
            [icon] => page_white_picture
            [read_only] => 
            [modifier] => 
            [bytes] => 1042035
            [modified] => Tue, 29 Mar 2016 17:39:12 +0000
            [size] => 1 MB
            [root] => dropbox
            [mime_type] => image/jpeg
            [revision] => 2
        )

        [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [rev] => 346830441
            [thumb_exists] => 1
            [photo_info] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [lat_long] => 
                    [time_taken] => Sun, 30 Sep 2012 00:54:59 +0000
                    [image_dimensions] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 324
                            [1] => 503
                        )

                )
            [path] => /389881_320848687954970_100000895238850_994084_116636550_n.jpg
            [is_dir] => 
            [client_mtime] => Tue, 29 Mar 2016 17:39:25 +0000
            [icon] => page_white_picture
            [read_only] => 
            [modifier] => 
            [bytes] => 134294
            [modified] => Tue, 29 Mar 2016 17:39:25 +0000
            [size] => 131.1 KB
            [root] => dropbox
            [mime_type] => image/jpeg
            [revision] => 3
        )
    )

    [headers] => Array
    (
        [server] => nginx
        [date] => Tue, 29 Mar 2016 18:58:05 GMT
        [content-type] => text/javascript
        [transfer-encoding] => chunked
        [connection] => keep-alive
        [x-content-type-options] => nosniff
        [set-cookie] => gvc=MTc0MjQ4ODE2ODkwMTIxMzU1NzEyNTIxNjM3MTc3ODIwODUwMjY0; expires=Sun, 28 Mar 2021 18:58:05 GMT; httponly; Path=/; secure
        [x-dropbox-request-id] => 62dd80f2be78340a6b8aaa62b1d66e16
        [pragma] => no-cache
        [cache-control] => no-cache
        [x-dropbox-http-protocol] => None
        [x-frame-options] => SAMEORIGIN
        [x-server-response-time] => 126
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say you call this array `$imagesArray`, to get the path of images it will be with a foreach loop :

```
<?php
  foreach($imagesArray['body'] as $image){
    echo "path is : ".$image->path;
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thank you sir :) .do u know how to get full path from drop box api?

Comment: You're welcome ! I'm not sure to understand what you're meaning by "full path" ?

Comment: i want to display image gallary through this paths but i think this paths are not enough for image gallary.

Comment: No idea for that sorry, I didn't use this API :/

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you've your result in $data variable than you can get all image paths as :

```
$imagePaths = array_map(function($image) {
    return $image->path;
}, $data['body']);
```

Now you've all image paths in $imagePaths variable.

Comment: Thank you sir :) .do u know how to get full path from drop box api?

Comment: I haven't use dropbox api so far. But might be there is an option to get base url as well. Will check and let you know.

Comment: Thnk you for your help sir.